# Which parking functions are not allowed?

Tags: combinatorics

The parking functions are the sequences  in which n cars ennumerated by $1\leq k \leq n$ have a preferred spot on the $k^{th}$ parking lot. If the $k^{th}$ parking lot is occupied, then the car takes the next parking lot.

There are $(n+1)^{n-1}$ parking functions of length n. When n = 3, the $4^2 = 16$ parking functions are
111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 211, 212, 213, 221, 231, 311, 312, and 321.

Then why 312 is one parking function? The car 3 preferred parking lot is the $3^{rd}$. He would never park at the first or second spot.

Comment: I think you are jumbling up parking "spaces" and parking "lots".  The usual definition just concerns parking "spaces".   $312$ is a valid sequence, as car $1$ prefers $3$, which is available.  Car $2$ prefers $1$ which is available, and car $3$ prefers $2$ which is available.  $322$ would be invalid, since:  car $1$ prefers space $3$ which is available, car $2$ prefers space $2$ which is available, but then poor car $3$ tries for the preferred space $2$, which is occupied.  It would settle for space $3$ but that one is also occupied.

Comment: [here](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/transparencies/parking.pdf) is a discussion of the standard use of the terms, just for reference.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott I fixed the formula, but still I don't understand.

Comment: @lulu Your link enumerates the spaces the opposite way. Car 1 should prefer place 1. But if it prefers place 3, then how does forms the PF 123?

Comment: @lulu Your link says "Car $C_i$ prefers space $a_i$", how do you interpret that "car 1 prefers space 3" if $C_1$ prefers space $a_1$

Comment: @libol: $123$ indicates that $C_1$ prefers space $1$, $C_2$ prefers space $2$, and $C_3$ prefers space $3$; not only can every car park, but every car can even get its preferred space.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity.  In the string $312$, we have $a_1=3, a_2=1, a_3=2$.  Thus, car $1$ should prefer space $3$ and so on.  Clearly, any sequence which is a permutation of $1, \cdots, n$ is valid.  Indeed, in such a sequence, everybody parks where they prefer.  Potential problems only arise if two or more cars prefer the same space.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott and lulu Thanks. I understand now. I thought that car k always preferred the place k, and the parking function encoded something like a possible outcome.

Comment: @libol: You’re welcome; I’m glad that we got it cleared up.